# I need to set checkbox checked when its value is true

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to set like if the value of check box is coming true then check box show selected if the value comes false check box gets selected but what happening its value getting true from the backend I am storing value in the state rules but it's not getting enable and if the value is getting true also I am not able to check and unchecked checkbox when value is true checkbox not check when value it's true why it's happening not sure also I am trying to set onChange but getting confused how to set onchange

**value coming from backend**

```
exactMatch: true
Match: true
```

**useRule component**

```
const [rules, setRules] = useState([]);
const fetchSearch = (data) => {
    axios
      .get(API_ENDPOINTS.SEARCH_UPDATE, data)
      .then((response) => setRules(response.data))
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("error", err);
      });
  };
```

**SearchRuleForm component**

```
export default function SearchForm() {

const { setRules, rules, fetchSearch } = useRule();
React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchSearchRule();
  }, []);

const handleCheckBoxChange = (e) => {
    setRules({
      ...rules,
      [e.target.name]: !rules[e.target.name]
    });
  };

 return (
 <Grid item xs={4}>
          <Box className={classes.formText}>
            <Checkbox
              name="exactMatch"
              checked={rules.exactMatch}
              color="primary"
              onChange={handleCheckBoxChange}
            />
            <Typography variant="subtitle2" noWrap={true}>
              Match
            </Typography>
          </Box>
        </Grid>
        
)
}
```

Comment: Please use punctuation marks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well not sure if I understood your question, I believe you are not able to configure your onChange function currently. This function should fix your problem

```
const handleCheckBoxChange = (e) => {
    setRules({
      ...rules,
      [e.target.name]: !rules[e.target.name]
    });
  };
```

Edit:
[Here's a codesandbox that I tried the solution on](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-payne-4xvnl?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: i have you imported useState into the component?

Comment: It'll be helpful if you can also attach a code snippet of the error

Answer (score 0):

implement the handleCheckBoxChange function like so:

```
const handleCheckBoxChange = (e) => {
    setRules((prevRules) => ({
      ...prevRules,
      [e.target.name]: !prevRules[e.target.name],
    }));
  };
```